# Merge localbranch to remote branch in GitHub

Tags: java, github, git-merge

I have all my changes in my local branch named `B` and I want to merge my local branch to the development branch named `B`. How can I do this in GitHub?

Also how can I ensure that my local changes are merged to the development branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. First you need to commit and push the local changes into the GitHub repository.
2. Need to send a pull request which is similar to the selecting the source and target branches.
```

For the same you can refer to https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request.

Then the other party can review and accept the pull request.

https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests